# Failed to load Manifest attribute - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, manifest

I am trying to export jar of a project via eclipse

when I run that jar it gives error "failed to load Manifest attribute"

although I give main-class-name in manifest file but it is not working

I put following in Manifest class

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: HangMan
```

For additional information: directory structure of Main class is

"/TestHangMan/src/test/HangMan.java"

what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, It(HangMan) is an Applet.Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the Project as "Runnable Jar" instead of "Jar". It will configure your Manifest for you just fine. Im not 100% sure, where that Error comes from, but I think it is because it is missing the classpath for your jar.

Comment: "Launch configuration" dropdown is blank and with out it eclipse doesnt let us export runnable jar... what to do?

Comment: Like Jens Birger Hahn already said (third step). You have to launch your application once in eclipse to let it create a launch configuration for your Main-File, then you will be able to choose it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to export simple Java programs as runnable JARs from Eclipse:

- Remove the MANIFEST.MF
- Move `HangMan.java` to the `src` folder (that's where your final code should be located)
- Run your program once inside of Eclipse to create a launch configuration.
- Choose `File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR File`
- In the dialog *Runnable JAR file Export* choose the correct launch configuration and destination. If you are not using any 3rd party libraries leave the rest as a default.

Try running the JAR, on Linux for example with

```
java -jar $HOME/tmp/HangMan.jar
```

Good luck!

**Update:**

OP's HangMan is a Java applet (see comments) :-).

Comment: "Launch configuration" dropdown is blank and with out it eclipse doesnt let us export runnable jar... what to do?

Comment: Did you run the program using `Context-Menu->Run->Run as Java application` as I noted in the third step? This should generate a launch configuration that you can select when exporting a runnable JAR. If not, leave another comment :)-.

Comment: Yes I run the application as "Java Applet" then tried to export but no use :(

Comment: "Java Applet" is wrong - have you created an Applet? You need to  have an application class with a `main(..)` method for an executable JAR, see the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/). Happy coding!

Comment: yes, I created applet( sorry I missed to mention it) ... Kindly tell me how to make executable jar of an Applet?

Comment: Applets are intended to be embedded in web pages - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) and the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/). If you want a runnable JAR, create an application :).